# Why is this compound sentence correct without a conjunction?

Tags: conjunctions

I saw this sentence in the Collins English Dictionary.

> He is more than a coach, he is a friend.

Can this sentence rephrased into,
"He is a friend more than a coach "
or
"He is not only a coach but also (he is) a friend "  without change of meaning?

Comment: ***No**!* your rephrased version doesn't mean the same thing! The original *He is more than a coach, he is a friend* means that ***in addition*** to being a coach, he's a friend too. If there's any suggestion that one of those labels applies more than the other, it's that he's ***primarily*** a coach (that being his ***default*** designation). But your rephrasing explicitly says that "friend" is a more appropriate description than "coach", which implies he's ***primarily*** a friend.

Comment: As for the lack of a conjunction, I'd say that role is effectively being performed by the comma (where the contrast introduced there could be more emphatically conveyed by a semicolon or a dash - or even a period before starting a new sentence. There's not normally any more explicit "conjunction" function word in such contexts.

Comment: There are two main clauses separated by only a comma. It would be better to separate them with heavier punctuation such as a semi-colon or even just a dash.

Comment: In this particular sentence, I would probably use a colon in place of the comma: "He is more than a coach: he is a friend."  The colon can indicate that the following part of the sentence is a kind of 'explanation' of the preceding, and the clause "he is a friend" *does* serve to explain *how* he is "more than a coach."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is frequently called a "[comma splice](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_splice)", which is often considered incorrect. However, people tend to have widely varying opinions about commas, so many people would consider this sentence to be fine, especially in casual contexts. I would instead recommend a semicolon, which more typically connects main clauses. (Other options are also possible, as mentioned in comments above.)

If you insisted on including a conjunction, then I'd recommend the following (using correlative conjunctions), as you suggested:

> He is not only a coach but also a friend.

However, your other suggestion ("he is a friend more than a coach") changes the meaning. The original sentence says that being a friend is in addition to being a coach but is not necessarily true to a greater degree. This suggestion says that being a friend is true to a greater degree than being a coach.